# What can we do with the C#-* tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I think we have a problem with the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) family of tags. It creates confusion and many people tag a question with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), and [c#-3.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0), etc. There is also confusion with the C# version != the .NET Framework version. The C# version isn't even widely known.

Can we eliminate the version-specific tags? I'm thinking we should gear to C# specific features like [c#-async](/questions/tagged/c%23-async) or [c#-linq](/questions/tagged/c%23-linq) (or just [linq](/questions/tagged/linq)).

Comment: Why eliminate version specific tags? If they are not required for a question, just remove them. If they are (i.e. the question is version specific) add them.

Comment: @Bart i think the problem is that not many people know what feature went with what version of C#.

Comment: Then retag appropriately.

Comment: `i think the problem is that not many people know what feature went with what version of C#` - I think that is exactly WHY the version specific tags are needed.  I don't know what features I have, but if I am using C#4 then someone who knows the features knows what I have access too.

Comment: I do agree that having multiple version tags in a post is unnecessary, but that's where [@Bart's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191469/what-can-we-do-with-the-c-tags#comment595796_191469) comes in.

Comment: I'd love to see mutually exclusive version tags, since tagging with multiple versions is nearly always the wrong thing to do, but that seems like a nightmare to implement well.

Comment: I agree somewhat, but the problem starts when you don’t *know* about the feature so you can’t tag your question with it.

Comment: @Wooble sometimes it is important to be able to tag with multiple versions. For example someone having an issue converting a C# 3.0 app to a C# 4.0 app. In the SQL Server world, someone might be mirroring from 2005 to 2012 or trying to restore a 2012 database to 2008.

Answer (score 18):

> Can we eliminate the version specific tags?

Absolutely not. They serve a specific purpose: to show which version of C# someone is using.

> The C# version isn't even widely know.

Then we should educate people on that, instead of penalizing those who *do* use the version numbers correctly. This is the point of my question: ["What are the correct version numbers for C#?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) which you should feel free to link to in other questions when there's confusion.

Comment: You got some C# tracker all over the network? :)

Comment: I'd put my money on a tracker that took him six to eight weeks to write.